# Im trying to save the data (date) into the array

Tags: arrays, loops, google-apps-script, sourceforge-appscript

Guys im trying to save it to the array but why it's saving the same in all slots?
[image]

I'm trying to make a loan sheet that will automatically ads up.
I was trying to save the date with 15 days to the array.

Comment: By the way, can you provide your script as text.

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your current issue is correct, I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be due to the pass by reference. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
array[i] = convert_date;
```

#### To:

```
array[i] = new Date(convert_date); // or new Date(convert_date.getTime());
```

- By this modification, the date object of `convert_date` is copied.

Comment: Thank you so much sir . may I know if you have a group,page or discord for app script developer?

Comment: @louie japitan Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From `Thank you so much sir . may I know if you have a group,page or discord for app script developer?` and the current situation, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @louie japitan If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?