# How do you run continuensly in app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

[image]

I finish making the basic script that I need to make a dept calculation automated. but I want it to run continuously like if I change something it will automatically change also. like i don't have to run the code every time I put something

Expecting to change every time I input in the sheet.

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your script, in your situation, I thought that the OnEdit trigger of the simple trigger or the installable trigger might be useful. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) And, there are several triggers in Google Apps Script. How about selecting one of them?

Comment: @Tanaike Do you have a group page or discord where I can join? The only program i know is python. i want to learn more on app script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From `@Tanaike Do you have a group page or discord where I can join? The only program i know is python. i want to learn more on app script.`, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it? Unfortunately, I thought that your reply is not related to your question and my comment. I deeply apologize that I replied the same reply to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76692892). If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?